# Public DNS, like provider

Tags: networking, dns

I have

1. VPS with public IP 1.2.3.4
2. Ubuntu + Wordpress, which opens from http://1.2.3.4.
3. Hosting provider who needs money for DNS A record.
4. Domain name mysite.com.

I know how to work with hosting and local DNS, but I can’t even google how to use the latter as a public one.

I know it's much easier to pay a host, but this is just for my education. I'll probably deploy public DNS somewhere later in the data center.

I need some tips on how to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: Are you even using Ubuntu? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].